# Laravel : How to access many to many relationship data Ask

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have category and subcategory table with many to many relationship

```
class Category extends Model {

    protected $table='categories';
    protected $fillable=['name'];
    public function subcategories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Subcategory\Models\Subcategory', 'categories_subcategories', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id');
    }
}
```

Subcategory

```
class Subcategory extends Model {

    protected $table='subcategories';
    protected $fillable=['name'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Category\Models\Category', 'categories_subcategories', 'subcategory_id', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

in controller

```
public function catSubList()
    {
        $subcategories = Subcategory::with('categories')->get();
        return view('Subcategory::category_subcategory',compact('subcategories'));
    }
```

But in view when i tried to access the data with following view

```
@foreach($subcategories as $row) 
                    <td>{{$i}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->name}}</td>  
                    <td>{{$row->categories->name}}</td>

@endforeach
```

I got the error like :

ErrorException in Collection.php line 1527: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.
How do i access `$row->categories->name` ? anyone with the suggestion please?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make another foreach() loop Because your subcategories belongsToMany categories. `row->categories` returns a collection, not an object. Thus the error.

```
<td>{{$row->name}}</td>  
<td>{{$row->categories->name}}</td>

@foreach($row->categories as $category)
    <td>{{$category->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

**Update**

Getting a category with all subcategories. Simply invert your query

```
$category = Category::with('subcategories')
->where('name', '=', 'cars')
->first(); 
//will return you the category 'cars' with all sub categories of 'cars'.
```

**Without eager loading**

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$subacategories = $category->subcategories;

return view('Subcategory::category_subcategory', compact('category', subcategories));
```

Comment: Instead of getting all the subcategories how do i print only those subcategories who has only the caregory ..means i'm getting list of subcategories..which i don't need..

Comment: Invert your query inside your controller. Check my updates.

Comment: That gives me this Error `QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subcategories.categories_subcategories' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `subcategories` where `subcategories`.`categories_subcategories` in ())`

I didn't put the where clasuse..i just use `$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();` and i got the Error as  i want the the list from database

Comment: You are trying to load all categories with all subcategories. And it's failing to load relationships. Definitely something to do with relationships here. Please try to load without eager loading to confirm my theory. See my update to see how to load without eager loading.